# How do I move all of my dotfiles to a custom directory?

Tags: macos, vim, vimrc, dotfiles

I'm a Mac user and I was wondering if there was a way to put all of my dotfiles to a `.config` folder to store all of them (something analogue to XDG Directories on Linux).

I was trying to set up a `.vimrc` file but as soon as I move it in `~/.config` a new one gets created in `~/`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

vim predates the XDG spec, and doesn't follow it. You could override the path to the config file using the VIMINIT variable in your shell profile,
according to https://tlvince.com/vim-respect-xdg

I've found it easier to just symlink `.vimrc` -> `.config/vimrc` and call it good.

Answer (score 3):

Since [7.3.1178](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/6a459902592e2a4ba68) vim will search for `~/.vim/vimrc` if `~/.vimrc` is not found.

```bash
$ cat "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME"/vim/vimrc
set runtimepath^=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim
set runtimepath+=$XDG_DATA_HOME/vim
set runtimepath+=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/after

set packpath^=$XDG_DATA_HOME/vim,$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim
set packpath+=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/after,$XDG_DATA_HOME/vim/after

let g:netrw_home = $XDG_DATA_HOME."/vim"
call mkdir($XDG_DATA_HOME."/vim/spell", 'p')

set backupdir=$XDG_STATE_HOME/vim/backup | call mkdir(&backupdir, 'p')
set directory=$XDG_STATE_HOME/vim/swap   | call mkdir(&directory, 'p')
set undodir=$XDG_STATE_HOME/vim/undo     | call mkdir(&undodir,   'p')
set viewdir=$XDG_STATE_HOME/vim/view     | call mkdir(&viewdir,   'p')

if !has('nvim') | set viminfofile=$XDG_STATE_HOME/vim/viminfo | endif
```

```bash
$ cat ~/.profile
export GVIMINIT='let $MYGVIMRC="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/gvimrc" | source $MYGVIMRC'
export VIMINIT='let $MYVIMRC="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/vimrc" | source $MYVIMRC'
```

> [G]VIMINIT environment variable will also affect Neovim. If separate configs for Vim and Neovim are desired then the following will be a better choice:

```bash
export GVIMINIT='let $MYGVIMRC = !has("nvim") ? "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/gvimrc" : "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.gvim" | so $MYGVIMRC'
export VIMINIT='let $MYVIMRC = !has("nvim") ? "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/vimrc" : "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nvim/init.vim" | so $MYVIMRC'
```

links:

- https://blog.joren.ga/vim-xdg
- https://tlvince.com/vim-respect-xdg

for more XDG dir support, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory

Comment: All the information necessary to answer the question must be here in this post. Links should only be used for attribution and perhaps further research. Please EDIT this question to improve it.

Comment: @music2myear fixed. sry for new here.

Comment: With the quality of that answer now, I think you'll do just fine here. Though I'll still suggest reading the Help section to learn how we're not the regular forum, and why. It'll help you get your bearings and fit in better.

Comment: @music2myear i'll read help section when free. thanks